# Python Logger change log level of third party module

Tags: python, logging

I import many third party modules that have various levels of logging (ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG) within them.  I would like to change the log level of a given log statement.

For example, I can do something like this:

```
import logging
import requests
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
requests.get('http://www.google.com')
```

This will output something like this:

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / 
HTTP/1.1" 200 4674
<Response [200]>
```

You can see that this comes from this [source code](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/master/src/urllib3/connectionpool.py#L204).  You can clearly see it's calling a `log.debug` which corresponds to the DEBUG message above.  How could I change this to `log.info` if I wanted to?

Note that I'm aware of `setLevel`, which would suppress messages below a certain level. That is not what I'm looking for.

**Suboptimal solution #1** I could extend the `requests` module, and overwrite that specific function.  I don't want to maintain

**Suboptimal solution #2** I could overwrite the constant for DEBUG within that module CRITICAL:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.logging.DEBUG = requests.packages.urllib3.logging.CRITICAL
requests.get('http://www.google.com')
CRITICAL:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com
CRITICAL:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://www.google.com:80 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4683
<Response [200]>
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can choose which level you want to see logs at, but you can't choose which level a third party library decides to log a particular message at without changing their source code. Could you give some context: why do you *want* to?

Comment: Are you aware you can call setLevel on individual modules' loggers instead of just the root logger?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you can accomplish what you want with a custom handler/formatter.